# How lambda expression resolve which method to call?

Tags: java, lambda

If I write a simple class:
[image]

```
package com.animal;

public class Human extends Animal {
    public void hisss() {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {System.out.println("New runnable instance");});
    }
}
```

Java is automatically invoking **Thread(Runnable runnable)** constructor. Why is it not invoking **Thread(String name)** instance?

This may be very primitive question but I am a primitive dev also. :-)

Not able to invoke **Runnable(String name)** constructor and also how can I call this constructor if I want?

Comment: `Runnable` is an interface and has no constructor. If you mean the constructor `Thread(String name)` you can simply use `new Thread("name of the thread")`

Comment: *Why is it not invoking Thread(String name) instance?* becuase you use a lamda/runable as parameter

Comment: BTW: please share code always as text not as image

Comment: I want to use lambda expression. I can use all these things via Java 7 but that is not the point actually. My question is about how Java 8 really resolve which method/ constructor  needs to be invoked.

Comment: When you write `()->{...}` your creating a lamba expression that has a no argument method that can implement a "functional interface". The Thread constructors are checked, and there is one constructor that has a functional interface with no arguments. `Thread(Runnable)` thus the java compiler will choose that constructor and your lambda expression is a Runnable. `String` is not a functional interface so there is no abiguity there.

Comment: @AHybrisDev The lambda-function you are passing conforms to the functional interface `Runnable`. That's how Java is able to resolve the correct constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is your expression:

```java
new Thread( () -> {System.out.println(...);}
```

Take a look at the lambda expression: `() -> {System.out.println(...);}`
It doesn't have input parameters and doesn't return any result.
Basically its similar to the function that is defined as `void someName()` (no parameters, and returns `void`)

Ok, now in Java when there is a functional interface it can be "substituted" with lambda expression.

In this case Java has to "chose" a suitable constructor, and indeed the interface `Runnable` matches this lambda:

```java
interface Runnable {
   void run(); // note, no input parameters, and it returns void
}
```

Class `Thread` has a constructor that accepts `Runnable` as a parameter:

```java
public class Thread {

    public Thread(Runnable runnable) {...}

     other constructors as well...
}
```

So Basically Java picks this constructor and calls it because the lambda expression that you specified matches `Runnable` interface

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas are resolved 'inside out'. You can try this to confirm it:

```
Object o = () -> System.out.println("Hello, World!");
```

does not compile. That's because all lambdas need to be 'resolved' - the compiler **must** know which *functional interface type* the lambda is representing.

A functional interface is any interface where you end up with precisely 1 method if you remove all methods which:

- Have a `default` implementation.
- Which match the exact signature of any method defined in `java.lang.Object` (such as the `toString` in `interface Example { String toString(); }`).

Whether you stick `@FunctionalInterface` on it or not, that is a functional interface (the annotation merely means: If the interface *is not* a functional interface, you get a compiler error - it's compiler-checked documentation).

From the context where you write a lambda, it must be possible for the compiler to determine exactly 1 functionalinterface type and the lambda is then interpreted as that type. The compiler goes pretty far in attempting to figure this out, though. Obviously, this works:

```
Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("Hello, World!");
```

That's because `Runnable` is a functional interface, and `Object` is not (it's not even an interface).

But, this also works:

```
void foo(String o) {}
void foo(Runnable r) {}

...

foo(() -> System.out.println("Hello, World!"));
```

Because the compiler's logic goes more or less as follows:

- Okay, foo is being invoked with 1 parameter. Let's see all the `foo` methods available that fit that. There are 2; one takes a `String`, the other takes a `Runnable` (in java, the identity of a method isn't just the name, it also includes the parameter types, hence, we have 2 completely unrelated methods here, both of which so happen to be named `foo`).
- Given that a lambda is being passed as param1, **only** those `foo` methods whose first param type is a functional interface type are even relevant. Applying that filter, only one `foo` method remains - the `foo(Runnable r)` one.
- Therefore that must be applied.
- Now we can resolve 'inside out' - that lambda is now interpreted as being a lambda for the functional interface `Runnable`, and it is parsed accordingly.

This mechanism both explains which method is 'selected', as well as how java knows how to compile even if you fail to specify the arg types of your lambda. Thus, for example, this works fine too:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.stream().filter(x -> x.length() < 5).toList();
```

That compiles and does what you think it does, but that is at first glance surprising. *How* does that work? Java is generally strongly, nominally, explicitly typed; so how does `x.length()` compile here, given that `Object` *does not* have a `length()` method?

That's because of the inside-out thing: The expression `list` is of type `List<String>`. Hence, the expression of `list.stream()` is of type `Stream<String>`. Hence, the only `filter()` method that is relevant is `filter(Predicate<? super String>)`, i.e. a function that takes in either Strings or Objects, and emits a boolean (why boolean? Because the only method in the `Predicate` functional interface's signature is `boolean test(X elem)` - and therefore the lambda must be an implementation of that method). Now the lambda is interpreted with these limits - `String` is used because it is more specific.

Even though your lambda does not explicitly say that the type of `x` is `String`, the compiler figures that out and doesn't parse the content of the lambda (here, `x.length() < 5`) without this knowledge. Hence, the compiler determines `length()` is fine, because `String` expressions have a `length()` method.